# Are Dominated Creatures Willing Recipients of Spells or Powers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am a psion, and I successfully manifest Mind Control onto a target creature. I would like to know if I can compel this dominated creature to become a willing recipient of a Mind Link just through the merits of Mind Control's effects alone.

Answer (score 5):

> Subjects resist this control, and any subject forced to take actions against its nature receives a new saving throw with a +2 bonus. Obviously self-destructive orders are not carried out.

It’s against almost-everyone’s nature to accept unknown spells from known enemies. If they know what the spell is, and it’s damaging enough, it may even qualify as “self-destructive” and thus simply not happen.

In the case of *mindlink*, of course, it’s **not** particularly damaging; if they **know** (e.g. make a sufficiently-high Spellcraft check) that you’re manifesting *mindlink*, it definitely shouldn’t qualify as “obviously self-destructive” and may not even trigger “against their nature” since it’s a harmless power.

Anyway, if they fail the save or the DM decides they don’t get one, you can control someone to make them willing<sup>1</sup> to accept the spell.

Or you could just manifest *mindlink* for 5 power points instead of 1, and waive the willing clause.

<sup>1</sup> Discussing these rules, even in context, skeeves me out.

Comment: It certainly would be easier to have them willing since the power DC is at the lower end of the spectrum, but I ultimately see what you're saying.

Comment: Wow, this is the only situation I've ever heard of where having a high spellcraft modifier could be a disadvantage.

Comment: It’s against almost-everyone’s nature to accept unknown spells from known enemies => This reasoning seems a bit weird, as it is also against everyone's nature to accept orders to move somewhere, fight something, etc. from a known enemy. This would lead to the subject getting a new saving throw every time you give it a new order. + wouldn't this also mean that a mind controlled enemy would constantly try to resist spells such as Cure Light Wounds or any other beneficial effects if they don't know what you are doing?

Comment: @Theik I'd argue yes. You have a fair point that it's very hard to be sure where to draw the line. I really wish the book had been less vague.

Comment: No, "attacking a combatant" is not against a soldier's nature.    "Attacking a civilian" is.  "Jumping off of a cliff" is against anyone's nature.  Receiving spells from an allied combatant isn't (unless like you pointed out they know that you're trying to harm them).

Comment: That's the thing @claudekennilol , does a mind controlled creature consider you their ally? Does it consider previously friendly combatants its enemies now? The book is hardly clear about it.